# Is there a deterministic (guaranteed) heap out-of-bounds checker? Is one theoretically possible?

Tags: c++, debugging, g++, heap-memory, instrumentation

Referring to utilities such as:

- Electric Fence (or DUMA for Windows)
- `gflags.exe -p /enable C:\Path\To\Your.exe /full` (Windows)
- mpatrol
- DrMemory
- Valgrind's memcheck (for Linux)
- `g++ ... -lmcheck`
- `g++ ... -fmudflap` (Linux)
- etc.

Is there one that is *guaranteed* to catch these accesses 100% of the time? (In the sense that every single time an actual illegal read/write occurs, it will be detected.)

I got a sense that most of them use probabilistic approaches. But is a deterministic such tool theoretically possible, or will it require special hardware?

I realise it's a tricky question requiring a lot of research and deep understanding, so I don't expect quick answers. But if anyone knows the answer already, please share!

Comment: Are you allowing the application to be instrumented by the compiler?

Comment: Doesn't Valgrind do just this?

Comment: @peppe Yes, if it comes to that. Can it instrument arbitrary pointer dereferencing? (As opposed to e.g. debug versions of STL containers.)

Comment: @H2CO3: no, it doesn't. For example if your access is so far out of bounds that it hits an unrelated allocation, then valgrind (and the usual techniques in general) won't catch it. You need some fairly heavyweight support to keep the size of every heap and stack allocation in a place where the compiler can emit code to check it (even if all that's available is a pointer into the middle of an allocation). I'm sure I remember someone on SO (James Kanze?) speaking of having written a C or C++ implementation that does this, but it's not a simple bolt-on.

Comment: @SteveJessop Aham. Well, that's an understandable implementation detail.

Comment: @H2CO3: sure, it's understandable, 100% checking is going to cost you. But I think in effect the question is, "is there a tool that does it anyway?". Java checks all array access, for example, but then Java has the advantage that you can't pass around a pointer into the middle of an array. If you wrote a C or C++ implementation that compiled to Java bytecode, with allocations represented by arrays and pointers represented by an array reference and an offset into that array, then once you've paid for those "fat pointers" you'd get this checking for "free" ;-)

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev: my point was more about the fact that without having the compiler's cooperation you can't detect stuff like this: `struct S { double a; int b[2]; }; S *s = new S[10]; for (int i = 0; i <= 2; ++i) s->b[i] = 42;` (that is, OOB access /within/ a single heap block allocated with `new[]`). W/o instrumentation, if you're just interested in accessing outside blocks returned by `new` or `new[]`, then the tools will give you 99.9% hits (of course for classes that didn't override them). The 0.1% missing is because your OOB could be so crazy that you end up in another valid memory area...

Comment: @peppe I agree. Once it's compiled with optimisations, it might as well have been custom-written assembly code. All the heap would see (through system calls, I am guessing) are "allocate 0x123 to 0x999", "read 0x555", "write 42 to 0x222", "read 0x0".